# How to plot median with 10% and 90% percentiles

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab, median, percentile

I have to make a plot of same data (I do it in Matlab). On the x-axis the time (in seconds) and on the y-axis the response time (in ms).

Now I have to do it with "Median with 10% and 90% percentiles".

What does this exactly mean? How do I have to do the plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use errorbars:

```
doc errorbar
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the percentiles? I think errorbars deal with standard deviation.

Comment: Just a plotting function. What to plot depends on the input...

Comment: Ther percentiles can be calculated with `prctile`.